# Select a top 10 list by number of times that person was entered

Tags: mysql

I have a table that keeps track of how many times a user accomplishes something.

I want a query that can help me create a top 10 list to display the leaders.

1. Anon - 10
2. Anon2 - 7
3. Anon 3 -3

My query which currently selects the entire count of something and only 1 user returns the following:

1. Anon - 20

Below is the query:

```
Select count(referral_person) AS C, referral_person 
from item_referral 
ORDER by count(referral_person) DESC;
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need `GROUP BY referral_person`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is missing a `group by` clause - but it has an aggregate function in the `select` clause. So MySQL gives you just one row, with the overall count of rows in the table and an arbitrary value of `referral_person`.

In most other databases, this would generate a syntax error - and in MySQL too, if sql mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` was enabled - which would make it much easier for you to spot the problem.

Also, to select the top 10, you can use `order by` and `limit`.

It seems like you want:

```
select referral_person, count(*) cnt
from item_referral
group by referral_person
order by cnt desc
limit 10
```